# От – до; какие требуются знаки при пояснениях?

Tags: пунктуация

> ...Он заказывает уникальные дворцовые и парковые ансамбли, он
>   изначально продумывает устройство «выставочных площадок», где каждый
>   желающий мог бы лицезреть **шедевры искусств от прикладного:
>   мебельного, швейного, ювелирного – до живописи  и скульптуры
>   величайших из творцов** Парижа, например.

А если так:

*...шедевры искусств – от прикладного: мебельного, швейного, ювелирного – до живописи  и скульптуры величайших из творцов...*

Два тире, понимаю, плохо. Ваши варианты, пожалуйста.

Или так:

*...шедевры искусств – от прикладного (мебельного, швейного, ювелирного и т. д.)  до живописи  и скульптуры величайших из творцов...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что не устраивает в исходной пунктуации? Автор обозначил однородные члены после обобщающего слова ***прикладного***. Тире - потому что предложение продолжается. Всё нормально.

*...Он заказывает уникальные дворцовые и парковые ансамбли, он изначально продумывает устройство «выставочных площадок», где каждый желающий мог бы лицезреть шедевры искусств от прикладного: мебельного, швейного, ювелирного – до живописи и скульптуры величайших из творцов Парижа, например.*

Можно и Ваш второй вариант:

*...шедевры искусств – от прикладного (мебельного, швейного, ювелирного и т. д.) до живописи и скульптуры величайших из творцов...*

Только здесь появляется поясняющее приложение, а была ли у автора цель выделить эту часть как пояснение?

*...шедевры искусств от прикладного до живописи и скульптуры величайших из творцов Парижа, например*

Answer (score 2):

Он заказывает уникальные дворцовые и парковые ансамбли, он изначально продумывает устройство «выставочных площадок», где каждый желающий мог бы лицезреть шедевры искусств от прикладного ― **мебельного, швейного, ювелирного** ― до живописи и скульптуры величайших из творцов Парижа, например.

Обособленный двумя тире пояснительный ряд.

Answer (score 1):

Только не двоеточие. Представьте себе, насколько стилистически неуместно видеть здесь обобщающее слово:

Каждый желающий мог бы лицезреть шедевры искусств **от следующих видов прикладного искусства**: мебельного, швейного, ювелирного – до живописи и скульптуры величайших из творцов Парижа, например. (?!)